# Trying to create a css transitition on hover of a h1 class

Tags: css-transitions

I have done this before, but it currently is not working and i cant figure out why. I would like the first h1 to rotate on hover just slightly. Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/YLXtd/1/

html

```
   <div id="headLine">
    <h1 class="fitText"><span class="highLight">Austin Kitson</span></h1>
    <h2 class="fitText"><span class="highLight">Marketing & Sales</span></h2>
  </div>
 </section>
```

css

```
#headLine {
  position: relative;
  top: 10em;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
 }
  #headLine .fitText {
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s; 
    padding:1em;

}

  #headLine .fitText:hover {
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg); }
  #headLine .highLight {
    background: rgba(151, 173, 191, 0.7);
    padding: 0.3em;
    color: #ebe6e0; }
```

​

Answer (score 0):

ha, turns out I forgot the vendor prefix for safari `-webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);` and I am using safari, silly me. I do this stuff all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :
It worked form me

```
    #headLine .fitText {
    -webkit-transition: 1.5s all ease;
            -moz-transition: 1.5s all ease;
            -o-transition: 1.5s all ease;
    transition: 1.5s all ease; 

}

  .fitText:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg); 
}
```

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/YLXtd/7/